# I got an error "Unable to load FastStringService". How do ı solve it?

Tags: flutter, compiler-errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\app_plugin_loader.gradle' line: 18
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> Unable to load FastStringService

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 713ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Change settings.gradle with this code:

include ':app'

def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile.toPath()

def plugins = new Properties() def pluginsFile = new File(flutterProjectRoot.toFile(), '.flutter-plugins') if (pluginsFile.exists()) { pluginsFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -> plugins.load(reader) } }

plugins.each { name, path -> def pluginDirectory = flutterProjectRoot.resolve(path).resolve('android').toFile() include ":$name" project(":$name").projectDir = pluginDirectory }

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Some explanation why this code solves the problem would not hurt.